# Indirect Addressing and Arrays

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```html
section .data
matrix dw 1,2,3,4,5
       dw 6,7,8,9,10
       dw 11,12,13,14,15
       dw 16,17,18,19,20
       dw 21,22,23,24,25
;defined as word in order to be used in stack as well as ASCII representing numbers in 2 bytes(1 byte for each digit)

msg db "The smallest value in this matrix is:",10
msgL equ $-msg



section .bss


smallVal resw 2

section .text
global _start
_start:

mov edi, 0 ;will be used in order to indicate when end of matrix has been reached
mov esi,0 ; will be used to indicate when end of row has been reached

mov ecx, [matrix + edi +esi*2]
```

I am working on a program which takes a matrix and tries to find the smallest value in the matrix. I am very new to programming,only having started programming java for about 4 months now and am now learning ASM as well. My question is regarding indirect addressing. What would the following statement actually do [eax + edx](given any arbitrary value stored in eax and edx). According to a website I found it effectively finds the effective address, but I am not sure what this means.

Thanks

Thanks for the quick responses. My problem really lies in how indirect addressing works for registers. I have attached a code snippet to the top of this thread. My problem lies on the line mov ecx,[matrix+edi+esi*2]. I am not sure effectively what this line does.

Comment: "Find" in this context doesn't mean what you want it to.  It does not perform any type of scan of a range of memory.

Comment: `[eax + edx]` is not a statement in x86 assembly. It can only appear as an operand to certain instructions (many of them actually). It can't exist by itself, and therefore doesn't "do" anything by itself.

Comment: ...however, if one were to interpret [eax+edx] in the spirit it is indended, it computes an address in memory which is the sum of the contents of the eax and edx registers.  [matrix + edi +esi*2] computes an address which is the sum of the memory address of "matrix", the contents of the edi register, and 2 times the content of the esi register.   Given such an address, a machine instruction may fetch the contents of the address from memory (mov to register), may store to that address (mov to memory), or may just use the address as a result (lea).  ....

Comment: ... it is worth nothing that a memory address refers to byte (8 bits), a word (2 bytes or 16 bits), a "d(ouble)word" (4 bytes or 32 bits), and on x64 CPUs, a "q(uad)word" (8 bytes or 64 bits).  Which *size* is referenced in encoded in the specific opcode used with the addressing mode.   You're pretty green to be trying to do this, best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code

```
mov ecx, [matrix + edi +esi*2]
```

fetches an element from the array but it is wrong! Since the array has been defined as words you have to use CX in stead of ECX.

To further understand the addressing mode.
EDI controls the outer loop and will evolve in steps of 10 from 0 to 40 (stopping at 50)
ESI controls the inner loop and will cycle from 0 to 4 (stopping at 5)

Comment: Ah thank you that explains alot. If you have the time, would you be able to look at another question I have posted. Also assembly related but MARIE instead of ASM. Its titled instruction encoding relating to MARIE assembly language. If you do not get around to it thanks regardless you've been a big help :)